# CSS & Jquery hidden panel sliding in does not work properly in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a hidden panel that gets displayed by adding a class to it with jQuery and then uses a CSS animation to control the slide in effect.

You can view a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kK3nn/1/).

The panel works fine in firefox. However in chrome when you click to display the hidden panel it does not animate it just appears, then when you close it and re-open the panel the animation starts working. It is only broken on its first load of the panel.

Below is my CSS and you can see my other code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kK3nn/1/):

```
.workIndvWrapper {
display: none;
z-index:9999;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 75%;
background-color: #ff0000;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-webkit-transition: .4s -webkit-transform ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .4s -moz-transform ease-in-out;
transition: .4s transform ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-moz-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  }
.close {
color:#fff;
font-size:20px;}
.showPanel {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
-moz-transform: translateX(0px);
transform: translateX(0px);
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#sauceThumb {cursor:pointer}
```

Comment: Why would you use 3D transforms to slide something in from the right, something that normally would take just a few lines of code?

Comment: How do you think it should be? Thanks

Comment: You could do this with css transforms, but since you're calculating so much in js anyway, jQuery animate would probably be easier. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fZDX6/1/ and https://api.jquery.com/animate/